# Getting cells value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting cell value using JQuery.

I have tried using the below code:

```
$("#table tr").each(function(){
    var result = $(this).find("td:first").html();
    alert(result);
});
```

But it returns string of all the first rows

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap" class="form-label">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth1HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth2HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth3HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jun-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth4HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jul-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth5HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Aug-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth6HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Sep-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth7HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Oct-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth8HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Nov-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth9HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Dec-17</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth10HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jan-18</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth11HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Feb-18</span>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <span id="lblAppMonth12HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Mar-18</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```

I expect the values "jun 17", "Jul 17".... in that order, but the actual output is a string of the rows.

Comment: I'm surprised it returns anything since you don't have a table with `id="table"`

Comment: Assuming you get the table selector right, this should only return `<span id="lblAppMonth1HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>`, ie the HTML content of the first `<td>` in the only `<tr>` in your table so your description does not match the code

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Did you forget your `<tbody>`?

Comment: stack overflow would let me post it all. @Phil

Comment: @VictorOnyebuchi did you reply to the wrong person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values with `text` - and use `.table` not `#table`:

```js
$(".table td").each(function() {
  var result = $(this).text().trim();
  if (result) console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap" class="form-label">
        <span id="lblAppMonth1HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth2HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth3HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jun-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth4HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jul-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth5HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Aug-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth6HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Sep-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth7HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Oct-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth8HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Nov-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth9HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Dec-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth10HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jan-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth11HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Feb-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth12HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Mar-18</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

If you want to collect all the rows, use an array:

```js
var rows = [...$(".table td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim()).filter(e => e);

console.log(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap" class="form-label">
        <span id="lblAppMonth1HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth2HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth3HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jun-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth4HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jul-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth5HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Aug-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth6HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Sep-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth7HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Oct-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth8HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Nov-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth9HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Dec-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth10HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jan-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth11HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Feb-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth12HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Mar-18</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(".table td")` as selector to loop thru the `td`s and use `text()` instead of `html()` to get the texts

```js
$(".table td").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap" class="form-label">
        <span id="lblAppMonth1HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth2HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold"></span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth3HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jun-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth4HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jul-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth5HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Aug-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth6HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Sep-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth7HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Oct-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth8HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Nov-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth9HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Dec-17</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth10HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Jan-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth11HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Feb-18</span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <span id="lblAppMonth12HeaderYr1" class="form-label-bold">Mar-18</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Really appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0):

You should add `id` to the table in order to call it `#table`.Also you can get the span text with `text()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr").each(function(){
    var result = $(this).find('span').text();
    //there are span elements that are empty, so i skip these ones
    if(result != ''){
        alert(result);
    }

  });
});
```